# Passenger on nginx is not reloading my changes ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, passenger

I have this query in one of my models (round.rb)
and whenever a round is created I want to generate all matches that belong to that round automatically.

```
Match.create(
  home_player_user_id: home, 
  away_player_user_id: away, 
  round_id: id, 
  first_pokemon: 2, 
  second_pokemon: 2, 
  third_pokemon: 3)
```

I expect to see something like:

`Match Create (0.8ms)  INSERT INTO "matches" ("home_player_user_id", "away_player_user_id", "round_id", "created_at", "updated_at", "first_pokemon", "second_pokemon", "third_pokemon") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["home_player_user_id", 1], ["away_player_user_id", 1], ["round_id", 1], ["created_at", "2018-11-25 10:08:14.422748"], ["updated_at", "2018-11-25 10:08:14.422748"], ["first_pokemon", 2], ["second_pokemon", 2], ["third_pokemon", 3]]`

in the logs.

However, I see only parts of that INSERT query being used like:

`D, [2018-11-25T09:45:03.240848 #4994] DEBUG -- :   Match Create (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "matches" ("away_player_user_id", "round_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["away_player_user_id", 1], ["round_id", 20], ["created_at", "2018-11-25 08:45:03.239943"], ["updated_at", "2018-11-25 08:45:03.239943"]]`

in this example home_player_user_id was `nil` which is completely fine, however I don't see any other fields like `first_pokemon`, `second_pokemon` and so on being set in the database, which breaks my whole logic.

This only occurs on production on an nginx server (https) using passenger.
I am restarting the passenger app with every deploy and thus I should have all the latest changes at hand.
On my local machine it works completely fine in (with `rails s`) in production and development

Does someone have a clue on what I could be missing here?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Did you make sure you have latest code version on server? Also you could try to restart passenger manually

Comment: Yea as I stated above whenever I deploy a new update I make sure to restart the passenger app so the latest version will be served, don't know if that can go wrong somewhere

Comment: Can you put the structure.sql for Match and the models code?

Comment: Schema: https://gist.github.com/dhartwich1991/3f18c1dde7977dc3a3ff146c99b6285b#file-schema-rb

Comment: The model that creates matches: https://gist.github.com/dhartwich1991/c58e72780fb3d8e1af2759aaaf1dff8d

Comment: Maybe it's also interesting to know that I added the first_pokemon etc. Fields with a later migration, but I don't think that could cause any problems

Comment: have you run the migration in production? If so, can you add more details about how you are using passenger?

Comment: Yea i am also running all migrations whenever I deploy a change, well I use passenger together with nginx, what do you need to know?

Comment: To debug this firstly I would go and check my code, schema and migration files **on server**, then check table schema in production db, then try to restart passenger manually to see if anything changes

Comment: If I log into the rails console and run the Match.create command there everything works as expected that's why it's even more weird and I don't get how this can even happen

Comment: https://gist.github.com/dhartwich1991/15fbf4e02998aae34a4a69cc849cd527 this is the deploy script I'm using to restart everything and get the latest changes on my server

Comment: Also bug might be in your code logic and you just passing `nils` as `first_pokemon` values.

Comment: But I do not do that? I generate a random number between 1 and 10, this would then also break in the development version on my local machine, no?

Comment: In addition to all that fuzz I have `after_create_commit` in `match.rb` and this thing only works partially... `send_welcome_message("Welcome to your game. Please enter the code above in order to get matched up and play your game. For coordination please use the Chat below.")
` doesn't work, while `send_result_message("We detected a free win. Setting free win user result to LOST")` works just fine ://

Comment: And both of them are creating a new Message object.. that's all...

Comment: It's about 90% chance that it's related to reloading code in your production setup. If you don't know how to test that, add a logger line in an action you can call, deploy the new version and see whether the line you added is present in logfiles.

Comment: And what do I do if it doesn't show up? I restarted already nginx and passenger

Comment: Can you edit the question and paste your Gemfile?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/dhartwich1991/83465921c3855d02a91be254a4f61aaa this is my gemfile updating the question

Comment: Out of ideas. Can you check that puma and spring are not running on your server?

Comment: Yea will try to see if I get home..are there more easy to use things than passenger that work with nginx

Comment: I checked and neither puma nor spring are running on the server ://

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was indeed that passenger and nginx were not reflecting the changes. I restarted the server machine completely and then it picked up the changes